# How do I successfully generate and send email verification link to new users that just signed-up using Firebase in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I am using a dependency service to create new users with their email and password as follows in my signupviewmodel:

```
token = await DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticator>().SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(Email, Password);
```

But, I want to be able to send an email for verification to each new user so that if their email has not been verified, I will not allow them to access the app.

I have already initialized the firebase app in MainActivity.cs as follows:

```
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    public static FirebaseAuth Auth;

    public event EventHandler<ActivityResultEventArgs> ActivityResult = delegate { };
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        InitFirebaseAuth(); //Create an instance of FirebaseAuth

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio) != Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio }, 1);
        }

        FormsVideoPlayer.Init();
    }
```

But, after successfully creating the new user and when I try to generate the email verification link, the app throws up this error:
System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

This is the code I am implementing in SignUpViewModel:

```
                var token = await DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticator>().SignUpWithEmailPasswordAsync(Email, Password);

            if (token != null)
            {
                var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
                var token2 = await auth.GenerateEmailVerificationLinkAsync(Email); 

                if (token2 != null) 
                { 
                  //SendEmailVerificationLink to New User
                }
            }
```

So, how do I get the FirebaseApp I initialized in MainActivity.cs to be referenced in the SignUpViewModel?

This is how the InitFirebaseAuth() was coded in MainActivity.cs:

```
public static FirebaseAuth Auth;
        private void InitFirebaseAuth()
    {

        var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .SetProjectId("MY_PROJECT_ID")
            .SetApplicationId("MY_APPLICATION_ID")
            .SetApiKey("MY_FIREBASE_API_KEY")
            .SetDatabaseUrl("MY_DATABASEURL")
            .SetStorageBucket("MY_STORAGEBUCKET")
            .Build();

        var _fireApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);

        Auth = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(_fireApp);
    }
```

Comment: which line causes the exception?

Comment: var token2 = await auth.GenerateEmailVerificationLinkAsync(Email);

Comment: is `auth` null?  If so, then you need to figure out why

Comment: auth is definitely null. I even tried initialising FirebaseApp in signupviewmodel but when it gets to "var token2 = await auth.GenerateEmailVerificationLinkAsync(Email);"  it would still flag the error. This is what I tried doing in the viewmodel:             var fbApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
            }); I have downloaded the json file where my Firebase credentials are stored and used Poweshell to include the file and its folder in the environment variable. Still, no show.

Comment: have you check this document? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#java